# I cannot get cookie from C# HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, cookies, request, response

I have a requirement to get cookies from login because i will apply this cookie in the same page. Here is my code

```
        string boundary = "41184676334";
        string username = "username";
        string password = "password";


        string login_post_data =
               "POSTDATA=-----------------------------" + boundary  +
               "\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"login\"" +
               "\n\n" + username  +
               "\n-----------------------------" + boundary  +
               "\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"" +
               "\n\n" + password  +
               "\n-----------------------------" + boundary  +
               "\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"clcode\"" +
               "\n\n" +
               "\n-----------------------------" + boundary  + "--";

        var cookies = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://site.com/cgi-bin/login.pl?logout");
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;



        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------" + boundary;

        request.Host = "site.com";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.Referer = "https://site.com/cgi-bin/login.pl?logout";
        //request.Headers.Add("POSTDATA", post_data);

       using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
       {
           requestStream.Write(StrToByteArray(login_post_data), 0, StrToByteArray(login_post_data).Length);
        }



        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();



        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            string temp = reader.ReadToEnd();
            richTextBox1.Text = temp;
        }


        foreach (string c in response.Cookies)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(c);
        }
```

The thing is "https://site.com/cgi-bin/login.pl?logout" is the same page after i logged in and i need to pass the cookie

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to log in and log out at the same time with your request, sent to URL

```
https://site.com/cgi-bin/login.pl?logout
```

Remove the `?logout` parameter and try again. Please update your question if it doesn't change anything.

Please explain further, what you're trying to achieve, so we can discuss if the code is correct.

Comment: The url https://site.com/cgi-bin/login.pl?logout is the login page after i put username and password and hit submit button the same url is on the address bar but the layout of the page is different. What i am trying to do is to get the cookie. Apparently my code didnt do the job.

Comment: The webpage after the login page suppose to have a cookie value in its document.cookie but it doesn't